# JSON to Java object conversion for map scenario (OpenAPI.yml)

Tags: java, json, openapi

I am trying to create POJO for below JSON to read this JSON data from excel file. But while reading below JSON with created DTO facing issue. Seems JSON is not in sync with created Java Pojo. Once pojo is fixed planning to create same structure in OpenAPI.yml.

Looking for generic Pojo conversion as acctKey,tranAmt and batchNum keys will vary depending on UI selection

JSON:

```
"filter": {
        "acctKey": {
            "filterType": "text",
            "operator": "OR",
            "condition1": {
                "filterType": "text",
                "type": "contains",
                "filter": "AC10"
            },
            "condition2": {
                "filterType": "text",
                "type": "contains",
                "filter": "AC103750"
            }
        },
        "tranAmt": {
            "filterType": "number",
            "type": "greaterThan",
            "filter": 2000
        },
        "batchNum": {
            "filterType": "number",
            "type": "equals",
            "filter": 1
        }
    }
```

Java snippet:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> filter
```

Comment: I don't see no POJO, you should use a JSON framework like JAX-RS or Jackson to do the mapping from/to Java. As you mentioned OpenAPI: The swagger tools can do that for you, too.

Comment: @ChristophDahlen Actually swagger tool will not give generic object creation, if we get new values logic would fail

Comment: Changed design to adopt generic JSON creation by openAPI